# Logging into two different file based on log message type

Tags: python, logging

i have a scenario. I have source a application file . I wanted to log error message into 'error.log' file and other warning or Info message into 'main.log' file . How can i do that ?

Note:
tried using loghandler (FileHandler). But its seems not working .
Can anyone please help

Comment: Take a moment and read the guidelines: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In the current form, I am afraid the question is not very informative.

Comment: Hi Ralvi. let me put it this way ... The scenario is simple . I want to store ERROR log in a different fille (like error.log) and other logs like INFO, WARN ,DEBUG in another file (main.log). . Would you still need little more explanation ?

Comment: Well, how do you expect the log to look like, json, cvs, something else? In principle, you just need to gather the data you need to log for each file, wait for some sort of log condition to be fulfilled and then log the data in separate files, i.e. errors in error log, info in info log etc

Comment: i got your approach . Can we do this only using default python logging module ?? I am not getting any idea to implement it

Comment: Again, without knowing what you've tried, or how you want your log to look like it's impossible to continue further this conversation.

Comment: Yes, this can be done using logging handlers and filters. You will need one FileHandler for each file. Each handler can have a logging level set. If you want to show ONLY Info level messages (as opposed to Info and more severe), you will need to apply a custom filter to the handler. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects